# How to scroll inside a Hybrid Mobile application using WebdriverIO and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, appium, ui-automation, webdriver-io

I have tried many pieces of code to make the scrolling work, but none of it is giving the desired results. I want to move to a specific element, not inside the viewport and interact with it. Below are the lines of code I tried, the uncommented one is the only line which is working but I want it to be dynamic. I want to scroll vertically. Note that the elements are in ALL CAPS. The last line is working in a weird way, it is not scrolling to the exact element but scrolls till midway to the element.

```
 
        // await this.progressCard.scrollIntoView()
        // await browser.scroll(0,2000).end()
        // await browser.moveTo(SIGNUP_CARD);
        // browser.touchPerform(RECENT_APPTS_TXT,0,2000);
        // await browser.touchPerform([
        //     {
        //     action: 'press',
        //     options: {
        //         x: 736,
        //         y: 800
        //     }
        //     },
        //     {
        //         action: 'moveTo',
        //         options: {
        //             x: 736,
        //             y: 1133
        //         }
        //     },
        //     {
        //         action: 'release'
        //     }
        // ]);
        // await browser.touchAction({
        //     action: 'tap',
        //     x: 736,
        //     y:1133,
        //     element: SIGNUP_CARD
        // })
        // await this.scheduleTherapyBtn.click()
        // await touchAction().press(RECENT_APPTS_TXT).moveTo(SIGNUP_CARD).release()
        // await browser.swipeUp(HOMESCREEN_HEADING,900,1);
        // await browser.touchScroll(1,900);
        // await browser.execute(SIGNUP_CARD => SIGNUP_CARD.scrollIntoView(), browser.element('accessibility id').value);
        // await browser.pause(5000)
       
        
        
        // await browser.execute("mobile: scroll", { strategy: 'accessibility id', selector : ASSESSMENT_CARD, direction: 'down'})
        // await this.signUpCard.click()
        // await browser.pause(3000)
        // await browser.touchAction([ {action: 'longPress', x: 794, y:1351 }, { action: 'wait', ms: 1000 }, { action: 'moveTo', x: 799, y: 1114}, 'release' ]);
        
        await browser.touchAction([{action:'press', x:700 , y: 1800},{action: 'wait', ms: 3000},{action: 'moveTo', x: 700, y: 600},'release'])
        //await browser.pause(3000)
        await browser.execute("mobile: scroll", {  strategy: 'accessibility id', selector : locator})
```

Comment: Did you read this? https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes, that is not working as well Raju